# Disabling all point of interests in angular-google-maps module doesn't work

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I'm trying to disable all point of interests when using [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps), it has a `GoogleMapsAPIWrapper` service which I'm trying to use after waiting for the map to load:

```
this.mapsLoader.load().then(() => {

  this.gm.setMapOptions({
    styles: [
      {
        featureType: 'poi',
        stylers: [
          {
            visibility: 'off'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'transit.station',
        elementType: 'all',
        stylers: [
          {
            visibility: 'off'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

But this seems to do nothing whatsoever. I've gone through the issues in the repo but haven't managed to find an answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show also the code where you use this options setting ..please

Answer (score 1):

Could be you should assingn also an element type eg:

```
mapProperties.styles = [
            {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [
                      { visibility: "off" }
                ]
            }
        ];
```